# Having problems using the FaceBook Javascript SDK cannot access UI

Tags: javascript, facebook, user-interface, sdk

I am trying to use the facebook javascript SDK to bring up a simple application request window. However when I attempt to do so absolutely nothing happens.

Here is my code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '151092658309155',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelUrl : 'channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
</script>
```

And then I call

```
<script>FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});</script>";
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is channel.html setup properly?  I can't think of much reason why you'd want to use your own channel file though..

Comment: I was just following the facebook example, my channel file contains the following info (as I was told by the facebook example to place in it)

    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

Comment: Try including the full URL to the channel.html.  I'm not sure if you need to, but it seems to be standard in the docs.  Also, have you used FireBug to see if any actual errors come up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be running this page from a URL that has been authorized on the [developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).[image: Facebook settings]

Comment: Oh thank you so much, but this appears to show the dialogue in a new window, all the other dialogues I have seen overlap the application page, is there somewhere else I should be looking for code that does this?

Comment: Never-mind I see now that to do this you simply have to call the function inside the page by an action rather than having it automatically open. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have an authenticated user, you can have this happen automatically on page load: http://www.fbrell.com/hidden/apprequest-on-load